# Efficient way to model this "peaking filter" function.

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling

**CONTEXT**

I'm working on an image processing algorithm, which uses pixel lightness values to determine how much the pixel should be darkened.

A small range of lightness values should be "selected" by the function, with a smooth transition to the unselected ones. The desired behaviour is visually described below:

```
X is the pixel lightness
Y is the multiplier to be applied to the pixel lightness later on
```

[image: Problem visual description]

I should be able to control 3 parameters:

- **A**: Filter center
- **B**: Some kind of Bandwidth
- **C**: Gain

**WHERE I AM NOW**

At first, I've tried using a simple parabola and clipping y values above 1:

$y = B(x-A)^2+(1-C)$

[image: Peaking filter with a clipped parabola]

However, the harsh clipped transition adds noise to the final image. I need a smoother transition.

So, I gave it another shot with two very expensive tanh curves, reflected by the filter center:

$y = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1-\Big[tanh(B(x-A)+B')+1\Big](C/2)  & \mbox{if } x \leq A \\
  1-\Big[tanh(B(A-x)+B')+1\Big](C/2)  & \mbox{if } x > A \\
 \end{array}
\right.$

[image: Peaking filter with tanh]

The results are better, however since I'll be processing 1080p videos with this algorithm, I don't think calculating tanh for every single pixel is a good thing.

**THE FINAL QUESTION**

Is there a way to model this behaviour without expensive operations such as `tanh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a polynomial is suitable, then consider

$$
f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4
$$

Solving for the $c_n$, using the conditions:

$$
f'(A)=f'(A+B/2)=f'(A-B/2)=f(A+B/2)=0 \quad; \quad f(A)=C
$$

Using your notation: $A$ is position of center, $B$ is width, $C$ is the height. *This is just for the peak: you need to subtract it from 1 to get the 'upside down version'*. The coefficients are

$$
c_0=\frac{C}{B^4}(B^4-8B^2A^2+16A^4) \\
c_1=\frac{16C}{B^4}(B^2A-4A^3) \\
c_2=-\frac{8C}{B^4}(B^2-12A^2) \\
c_3=-\frac{64CA}{B^4} \\
c_4=\frac{16C}{B^4}
$$

Here is a plot with $A=1$, $B=0.1$, $C=2$

[image]

Of course we are only interested in the graph between $A-B/2 \ < x < \ A+B/2$. It's tangent to the horizontal at the boundary.